# Excel: Four columns with different lengths and data values, need to find matching values

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a sheet with 4 columns of data. The first two columns show the name of a stock, followed by a PipDigit. These two values are connected and must not be seperated. The other 2 columns are another set of stock names and accompanying PipDigits. I want to do several things:

First, compare the stock names in each column and arrange it in such a way that matching stock names are aligned. The columns have different lenghts.

Second, I want another column to display which matching stocks have different PipDigit values. For example if for an Ebay stock I have a PipDigit of 2 in the first set of columns, and a PipDigit of 4 in the second set of columns, I would like to see message saying "different" or something similar. I have included a screenshot of the file.

If anything is unclear please let me know

[This is the file in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdCXh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe from your question you are looking for the corresponding record in columns E/F for the 'Symbol' in column A.

The easiest way to get this data would to perform a VLOOKUP on the first column, looking at the data in columns 3/4.

In cell C2 you want the following formula:
`=VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,FALSE)`

This will give you the corresponding pip-digit from column F.

Now in cell D2, enter the following formula:
`=IF(B2=C2,True,False)`

This will give you a column telling you whether the pip digits match.

Drag these two formulas down to replicate for each row of the table on the left.